# GameScene sharedGameScene versus GameScene node

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, singleton

I am porting bits of the game engine to another game code's and I have two concerns.

The code:

```
-(void) checkForBulletCollisions
        {
                Enemy* enemy;
                CCARRAY_FOREACH([batch children], enemy)
                {
                if (enemy.visible)
                {
                        BulletCache* bulletCache = [[GameScene sharedGameScene] bulletCache];
                        //etc etc
```

The GameScene in the project I am porting this code to is not a singleton like the GameScene  is in the above code.

Here is the GameScene's interface code:

```
@interface GameScene : CCScene
    +(void) newGame:(NSString*)levelFile;
    -(void) reloadGame:(NSString*)levelFile;
@end
```

When porting the top lines of code I replaced the top line of code with:

```
BulletCache* bulletCache = [[GameScene node] bulletCache];
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: [GameScene node] return a new GameScene instance, so you won't get the expected result. The class that has the method checkForBulletCollisions should have a reference to the GameScene instance so that you can call bulletCache = [theGameSceneInstance bulletCache]; Further more, GameScene is not a good candidate to be a singleton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As hiepnd stated - the node method creates a new autoreleased instance. The code you are porting however is calling a singleton. I'm going to assume that the singleton is the 'current scene' - and therefore your task in porting is to find the top node in the node hierarchy - confirm that it is indeed of Class GameScene, and then retrieve yur reference to the bulletCache from it.

The current scene can be retrieved from the director as follows:

```
CCScene *currentScene = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
GameScene *gameScene = nil;
if ([currentScene isKindOfClass:[GameScene class]]) gameScene = currentScene;
BulletCache *bulletCache = [gameScene bulletCache];
```

Comment: thanks for the tip! Btw, in my project, the top node of BulletCache is the LevelObject class, which itself is a subclass of CCNode, while the other project's code has accessors for bullets in its GameScene, which is why it's calling the GameScene singleton.
@hiepend I agree with you, that is why I am making my Bullet/BulletCache classes subclasses of the pre-existing LevelObject class, which is a subclass of CCNode